# TSQL Case When Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a statement in my select that is functioning as intended that looks like this:

```
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT winnerID
                   FROM   empowermentWinners
                   WHERE  entryID = AA.[entryID]) 
                THEN (SELECT 'Yes' FOR    XML PATH ('isWinner'), TYPE, ELEMENTS)
                ELSE (SELECT 'No' FOR    XML PATH ('isWinner'), TYPE, ELEMENTS) 
        END AS XML) AS isWinner)
```

It outputs the XML for me like so:

```
<isWinner>Yes</isWinner>
```

Is there a way within this statement to include items from the select statement?

For example if I wanted to include the winnerID that im selecting; is it possible to return that as well like so?

```
<winnerID>1234</winnerID>
```

I can change these to inner selects if needed but was just curious if it could return more than one piece of information in its current format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the subquery into the `from` section and correlate it using `outer apply`:

```
select (select case when oa.WinnerId is not null then oa.WinnerId else 0 end as [Winner] for xml path(''), type, elements)
from dbo.MyTable aa
    outer apply (
        select * from dbo.EmpowermentWinners ew where ew.EntryId = aa.EntryId
    ) oa
```